# Adding clang-format tool to existing project in makefile

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, clang-format

I want to add clang-format tool to my project to follow specific coding styles. I already have a project and makefile for it. How should I integrate the clang-format tool into my project using makefile?

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish. Do you want a make target that formats all your code in a directory? Are you using a version control system?

Comment: Yes exactly. Yes I am using git vcs

Answer (score 2):

First you will need `clang-format` and `clang-format-diff.py` on your path.

Here is a python script that formats all c/c++ source/header files in a directory recursively:

```python
import os

cpp_extensions = (".cpp", ".cxx", ".c++", ".cc", ".cp", ".c", ".i", ".ii", ".h", ".h++", ".hpp", ".hxx", ".hh", ".inl", ".inc", ".ipp", ".ixx", ".txx", ".tpp", ".tcc", ".tpl")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("src"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(cpp_extensions):
            os.system("clang-format -i -style=file " + root + "/" + file)
```

I have a `.clang-format` file with a custom style and thus the `-style=file` parameter. `-i` is for inplace editing.

This is probably not the most pythonic way but it works for me. You can rewrite it in bash.

You can add a `format` target to your makefile like this:

```
format:
    python the_script.py
```

If you wish you can format only the dirty files in git like this (as stated [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)):

```
format:
    git diff -U0 HEAD^ | clang-format-diff.py -i -p1
```

Comment: If I create my own .clang-format. it does not work. I have kept it in same directory where the_script.py is? do i have to keep somewhere else?

Comment: @NitinD you have to keep the ```.clang-format``` config file where the sources are - not where the py script is.

Comment: Is there way to keep the .clang-format file somewhere else and use it in my sources directory. I dont want to have .clang-format file everywhere in my each sources directory.

Comment: @NitinD you can place the file in the root directory - you don't have to place it in every subdirectory. But I don't think it can be specified to be elsewhere.

Comment: Let say
1. I keep .clang-fomat in /tmp
2. i have source file: /home/ndeokate/test1.c
3. cd /tmp && clang-format -i style=file /home/ndeokate/test1.c
Output
----------
No such file or directory
Can't find usable .clang-format, using LLVM style

Comment: @NitinD clang-format will search for the file in these directories in this order: 1. ```/home/ndeokate/``` 2. ```/home/``` 3. ```/``` and will not go in ```/tmp/``` - this is explained in the documentation. Do you consider this question answered?

Comment: Do you point me to documentation? 
Yes this is answered, just documentation link would be helpful

Comment: @NitinD [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) it says this: ```When using -style=file, clang-format for each input file will try to find the .clang-format file located in the closest parent directory of the input file.```. It also says that if stdin is used, the search for the ```.clang-format``` file starts from the current working directory (so after ```cd /tmp``` if you invoke clang-format and give it your code through stdin (with piping) you might do what you want)